# Tkinter - differences in font sharpness between python versions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, rendering, font-size

I have a `tkinter` GUI app that works fine with python 3.6.0 version.

when I upgraded to python 3.10.6 version the texts of widgets become very blurry.

when I did a comparison I found out that font sharpness is much better in python 3.6 version than in python 3.10.
(image attached)

how to solve this issue?

[image: Comparison]

left - 3.6.0
right - 3.10.6

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter seems to have decided to start supporting [antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) between Python 3.6 and 3.10 on your OS. However, this antialiasing support seems to be dependent of the platform. For example, on my Windows 10 PC, I also get some antialiasing, but the render is not that blurry:

[image]

Possible fixes:

- Use a font that does not have antialiasing, such as `Minecraft`, `FixedSys`, `Pixellari` for example.
- Use an earlier Python version to remove Tkinter's antialiasing support.
- You can try this MRE and compare the rendering with `Label`s or text in `Canvas`es, and if one or the other is better, use it:

```py
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Antialiasing comparison')

fonts = ['Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Times New Roman', 'Courier New', 'fixedsys']
sizes = [12, 20]

Label(tk, text='Labels', fg='blue').grid()
Label(tk, text='Canvas text', fg='blue').grid(column=1, row=0)
antialias = Frame(tk)
antialias.grid()
alias = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=sum(sizes)*len(fonts)*4)
alias.grid(column=1, row=1)

y = 15
for font in fonts:
    for size in sizes:
        for bold in [(), ('bold',)]:
            b = ' bold' if len(bold) else ''
            kwargs = {'text': '%s %d%s' %(font, size, b), 'font': (font, size)+bold}

            # display antialiased labels in Frame
            Label(antialias, **kwargs).pack()

            # display aliased labels in Canvas
            alias.create_text(200, y, **kwargs)
            y += size*2

tk.mainloop()
```

- Try to use an older Tkinter on a newer Python if you still want to use a newer Python version. You can download older Python and library files [on the `cpython` Github repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/). Then, you will have to extract `cpython-x.x.x/Lib/tkinter` into you program's directory as, for example, `oldtkinter`, and import it into your script in place of Tkinter.
- Since the problem comes from your OS, maybe disable antialiasing. I know on Windows you need to type Win+R, then `systempropertiesperformance.exe`, then uncheck "Smooth edges of screen fonts", but you surely can find the same fix on Linux. I won't do this for you since I very well may be wrong, not running a Linux distribution.

Working result on Windows 10:

[image]